# Why "\\s" with "rlike" in Spark SQL not work?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

It's strange the "\s" not work, as the code below:

```
scala> case class Item(id: Int, name:String)
defined class Item

scala> val df = Seq((1, "hello"), (2, " "))
df: Seq[(Int, String)] = List((1,hello), (2," "))

scala> df.toDF("id", "name").as[Item].filter("name rlike '\\s'").show()
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

As [LanguageManual UDF described](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), `rlike` need double escaped pattern `\\s`.

While in the spark-shell, Scala has escaped once. So more `\` is needed:

```
scala> df.toDF("id", "name").as[Item].filter("name rlike '\\\\s'").show()
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  2|    |
+---+----+

scala> df.toDF("id", "name").as[Item].filter("name rlike '\\\\w'").show()
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|hello|
+---+-----+
```

Or use strings without escape, like:

```
scala> val er = """name rlike '\\s'"""
er: String = name rlike '\\s'

scala> df.toDF("id", "name").as[Item].filter(er).show()
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  2|    |
+---+----+
```